# SVG fill colour in image with shadows

Tags: image, svg, colors, shadow, fill

User upload the picture of wall. The wall may contain shadows and objects. PHP convert it into svg image. Is it possible to change the colour of the wall with shadow into specific colour. Please inform is there any javascript api to do the task.

Comment: set the fill attribute to the colour you want.

Comment: Thanks. Whether shadow area colour also will be changed.

Comment: Who knows, you haven't posted any code so we'd just be guessing.